# How can I retrieve dxgiDevice from IDXGIFactory4 or ID3D12Device

Tags: c++, directx-12

How can I retrieve dxgiDevice from IDXGIFactory4 or ID3D12Device

```
    CreateDXGIFactory2(DXGI_CREATE_FACTORY_DEBUG, IID_PPV_ARGS(&m_dxgiFactory));
    GetHardwareAdapter(m_dxgiFactory.Get(), &hardwareAdapter);
    D3D12CreateDevice(hardwareAdapter.Get(), D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0, IID_PPV_ARGS(&m_device));

    // some initial code

    // Create the Direct2D device that links back to the Direct3D device
    ComPtr<ID2D1Device1> d2Device;
    d2Factory->CreateDevice(dxgiDevice.Get(), d2Device.GetAddressOf());

    // some initial code

    ComPtr<IDCompositionDevice> dcompDevice;
    DCompositionCreateDevice(dxgiDevice.Get(), __uuidof(dcompDevice),
 reinterpret_cast<void **>(dcompDevice.GetAddressOf()));
```

Comment: The pseudo-code above does not show you checking any ``HRESULT`` values. You need to explicitly check them for ``SUCCEEDED`` or ``FAILED``. Which one is failing and with what value?

Comment: For DirectX 12 interop with Direct2D/DirectWrite, you use [D3D11On12CreateDevice](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d12/direct3d-11-on-12). Alternatively, you can use [DXGI Shared Surfaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3darticles/surface-sharing-between-windows-graphics-apis).